# deleting streamplots (matplotlib) without clearing the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

i've always found help here until now. i've been looking for a solution of my problem very long and i might be blind by now.. i hope you can help me with this one:

i've built a python-program that plots either the direction field (quiver) or the streamplot. since there might be other data in the graph (e.g. trajectories) i can't just clear everything and replot. instead i want to delete single elements. this works perfect for everything except the streamplot.

so, the streamplot consists of lines and arrows. stored in the variable `sl` i can simply call `sl.lines.remove()` to delete the lines. this doesn't work for the arrows, though.
how do i delete these?

edit:
so here's a little code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp

streamplot = None

def mySystem(z):
    x, y = z
    return y, -x


def stream():
    xmin = -10
    xmax = 10
    ymin = -10
    ymax = 10

    N = 40
    M = int(N)
    a = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,N)
    b = np.linspace(ymin,ymax,N)

    X1, Y1 = np.meshgrid(a,b)
    DX1, DY1 = mySystem([X1,Y1])

    global streamplot
    streamplot = pp.streamplot(X1, Y1, DX1, DY1, density=2, color='#b5b5b5')

def removeStream():
    global streamplot
    streamplot.lines.remove()

    #doesn't work: streamplot.arrows.remove()

stream()
removeStream()
pl.show() # arrows still here!
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're unlikely to be able to help you without seeing more context. Could you post your actual code here and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Be sure also to check the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Thanks!

Comment: Christian is right. But I faced something similar a while ago so maybe I can help. In the documentation of [streamplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot), they say that the function returns a container with two attributes: `lines`and `arrows`. So, similar, to `sl.lines.remove()`, you will find a `sl.arrows.remove()` method -- which should do your job,

Comment: @redrivercrayon - You should post that as an answer. I was about to, but you beat me to it!

Comment: @JoeKington I did not because I was not sure. And I was right. What I suggested above should have worked in principle but it does not because it is not implemented yet (for some strange reason). I tried to remove the arrows in a test example and got a `NotImplementedError: cannot remove artist` in `.../site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 137`. I guess the correct thing would be to put this in the Matplotlib mailing list or forum.

Comment: i just updated my question. sl.arrows.remove() is supposed to work, but it doesn't. bug? edit: damn. so no help here?

Comment: no, not a bug because it raises a `NotImplementedError`. more like a feature in an upcoming version. you should get in touch with them if this is really critical for you.

Comment: so the best thing is to hope that it will be implemented soon? :-/

Comment: @user2925620 The best way to make sure it gets implemented soon is to do it your self and submit a PR!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround for `PatchCollection` not having a working `remove` method.

The arrows are added to `ax.patches`.  Assuming you don't have any other patches in the plot (e.g. a bar plot uses patches), you can just do `ax.patches = []` to remove the arrows.

Ideally, you'd get the patches from the `sl.arrows` `PatchCollection`, but it doesn't actually store a reference to the patches themselves, just their raw paths.

If you do have other patches in the plot, you could remove all instances of `FancyArrowPatch` instead.  E.g.

```
keep = lambda x: not isinstance(x, mpl.patches.FancyArrowPatch)
ax.patches = [patch for patch in ax.patches if keep(patch)]
```

Comment: that looks pretty neat, but i will try that FanxyArrowPatch-instance-hack tomorrow! thank you very, very much! you really helped me a lot!

Comment: @user2925620 - Not a problem! Good luck!

Comment: I just stumbled over this. Great solution! _...except syntax._ This should instead read: `ax.patches = [patch for patch in ax.patches if not isinstance(x, mpl.patches.FancyArrowPatch)]`.

Comment: Also, this behaviour prohibits use of multiple streamplots in an animation. (Unless upstream Matplotlib has finally fixed this? For stability, I'm afraid I'm currently on 1.4.3.) Cheers as ever, Joe!

Comment: @CecilCurry - Thanks for the catch!  That reminds me... I meant to send in a pull request for this and never did. This is still present in 1.5, as well.