# Matplotlib Animation of Streamplot of Bifurcation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am currently trying to animate the dynamics of a typical saddle node bifurcation ode: dx/dt = r + x^2. Snapshots at specific values of r are realised with the streamplot function from r = -1 to 1. Unfortunately the init function and the animate function are not working properly because .set_array does not work for streamplots. I am also not sure how to update the streams at each iteration in the animate function. My question is how I should modify the animate and init function so that the funcanimation function gives a proper animated plot of the flows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation


nx, ny = .02, .02
x = np.arange(-15, 15, nx)
y = np.arange(-10, 10, ny)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
dy = -1 + Y**2
dx = np.ones(dy.shape)

dyu = dy / np.sqrt(dy**2 + dx**2)
dxu = dx / np.sqrt(dy**2 + dx**2)


color = dyu
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
stream = ax.streamplot(X,Y,dxu, dyu, color=color, density=2, cmap='jet',arrowsize=1)
ax.set_xlabel('t')
ax.set_ylabel('x')

def init():
stream.set_array([])
return stream

def animate(iter):
    dy = -1 + iter * 0.01 + Y**2
    dx = np.ones(dy.shape)
    dyu = dy / np.sqrt(dy**2 + dx**2)
    dxu = dx / np.sqrt(dy**2 + dx**2)
    stream.set_array(dyu.ravel())

    return stream

anim =   animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=100, interval=50, blit=False, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Looking at [the documentation for `streamplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.streamplot.html?highlight=streamplot#matplotlib.axes.Axes.streamplot), it says it returns an object containing "`stream.lines`" (`LineCollection`) and "`stream.arrows`" (list of `FancyArrowPatch`). I think you'll have to update the parameters of each of those separately.

Comment: Ok, with your tip I managed to remove the lines in the init function, but not the arrows because. stream.arrows.remove() is not implemented yet. Furthermore the intial frame gets its arrows removed but not the following frames, i.e. the animation continuously adds lines and arrows. So I guess I have to implement a stream.lines.remove() somewhere in the animate function?

Comment: This may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621521/deleting-streamplots-matplotlib-without-clearing-the-graph

Comment: i tried the code from the answer from your link but it wouldnt delete the arrows. moreover the animation works but the streamlines are only deleted in the initial frame. after that the streamlines pile up from each previous frame. wasn‘t the init function supposed to clear the frames after each animation step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this by clearing the lines and arrows in every iteration:

```
ax.collections = [] # clear lines streamplot
ax.patches = [] # clear arrowheads streamplot
```

So, I modified your code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation


nx, ny = .02, .02
x = np.arange(-15, 15, nx)
y = np.arange(-10, 10, ny)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
dy = -1 + Y**2
dx = np.ones(dy.shape)

dyu = dy / np.sqrt(dy**2 + dx**2)
dxu = dx / np.sqrt(dy**2 + dx**2)

color = dyu
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
stream = ax.streamplot(X,Y,dxu, dyu, color=color, density=2, cmap='jet',arrowsize=1)
ax.set_xlabel('t')
ax.set_ylabel('x')

def animate(iter):
    ax.collections = [] # clear lines streamplot
    ax.patches = [] # clear arrowheads streamplot
    dy = -1 + iter * 0.01 + Y**2
    dx = np.ones(dy.shape)
    dyu = dy / np.sqrt(dy**2 + dx**2)
    dxu = dx / np.sqrt(dy**2 + dx**2)
    stream = ax.streamplot(X,Y,dxu, dyu, color=color, density=2, cmap='jet',arrowsize=1)
    print(iter)
    return stream

anim =   animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=100, interval=50, blit=False, repeat=False)
anim.save('./animation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=60)
# plt.show()
```

[image: animation]

Answer (score 0):

**CAUTION:** @SebastianBeyer's [previously working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56304195/5049231) no longer works in 2022. For unknown (and presumably indefensible) reasons, Matplotlib now prohibits attempts to manually replace the `axes.patches` list by raising a non-human-readable exception resembling:

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute 'patches'
```

Thankfully, yet *another* working workaround exists. Inspired by @Sheldore's [working answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61932726/5049231), you must now iteratively search for and remove all `matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch` child artists from the streamplot's axes: e.g.,

```py
# Rather than this...
ax.patches = [] # clear arrowheads streamplot

# ...you must now do this.
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
for artist in ax.get_children():
    if isinstance(artist, FancyArrowPatch):
        artist.remove()
```

In full, the post-2020 working solution is now:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch


nx, ny = .02, .02
x = np.arange(-15, 15, nx)
y = np.arange(-10, 10, ny)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
dy = -1 + Y**2
dx = np.ones(dy.shape)

dyu = dy / np.sqrt(dy**2 + dx**2)
dxu = dx / np.sqrt(dy**2 + dx**2)

color = dyu
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
stream = ax.streamplot(X,Y,dxu, dyu, color=color, density=2, cmap='jet',arrowsize=1)
ax.set_xlabel('t')
ax.set_ylabel('x')

def animate(iter):
    ax.collections = [] # clear lines streamplot

    # Clear arrowheads streamplot.
    for artist in ax.get_children():
        if isinstance(artist, FancyArrowPatch):
            artist.remove()

    dy = -1 + iter * 0.01 + Y**2
    dx = np.ones(dy.shape)
    dyu = dy / np.sqrt(dy**2 + dx**2)
    dxu = dx / np.sqrt(dy**2 + dx**2)
    stream = ax.streamplot(X,Y,dxu, dyu, color=color, density=2, cmap='jet',arrowsize=1)
    print(iter)
    return stream

anim =   animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=100, interval=50, blit=False, repeat=False)
anim.save('./animation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=60)
# plt.show()
```

Thanks alot, post-2020 matplotlib. `</facepalm>`